# Wagtail Heroku Hosting Deployment

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, wagtail

I am trying to deploy my wagtail app to Heroku but I have run into an issue that I do not understand.

My backend admin works perfectly 
https://idealbackend01.herokuapp.com/admin

But my front end says an internal server error
https://idealbackend01.herokuapp.com/

I followed this approach and used whitenoise for static storage.
https://github.com/CodingForEverybody/wagtail-heroku-deployment/blob/master/README.md

Then I got s3 connected following this for media files this works as I was able to upload a file to my s3 bucket. 
https://wagtail.io/blog/amazon-s3-for-media-files/

During my Heroku build, I didn't get any errors, and there were no issues in the logs.

Ask I said the backend renders fine and everything works as expected, but nothing on the front end seems to be working.

Is this possibly due to the sites hostname and port? It is currently set at localhost and 80
Then I tried to set it to my default URL https://idealbackend01.herokuapp.com/ but neither solution seems to be fixing the front end issue.

Is there a reason the admin would not be loading but the frontend wouldn't.

Any direction you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to know what might be going wrong here, but I don't think it's to do with your sites setting. Try watching the Heroku logs - which should be available at https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/idealbackend01/logs - while you reload the home page.

Comment: I will. Thanks for the tip!